# innerHTML = HTML & JQuery, JQuery doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, jquery

I am using jscript to insert HTML.

```
function pluginOrderTotals(OrderTotals) {
var orderTotalsHTML = "";
if (OrderTotals != "") {
    orderTotalsHTML = "<a id='OrderTotals' href=''>Order Totals</a><p id='OrderTotalText'>" + OrderTotals + "</p><script>$('#OrderTotals').click(function () {          $('#OrderTotalText').toggle('fast');});";
}
document.getElementById("pluginWidgets2Div").innerHTML = orderTotalsHTML;}
```

The HTML part of the variable is passed just fine, but the JQuery animations do not work. If I hard code this in the HTML like below the animations work fine.

```
    <div id="pluginWidgets2Div">
        <a id="OrderTotals" href="">Order Totals</a>
            <p id="OrderTotalText">Hiya<br />
            Such interesting text, eh?</p>
        <a id="FreightView" href="">View Freight</a>
            <p id="FreightViewText" style="display: none">Hiya<br />
            Such interesting text, eh?</p>
        <a href="">Another (3)</a>
        <a href="">Menu item 4</a>
        <a href="">One more (5)</a>
        <script>
        $("#OrderTotals").click(function () {
        $("#OrderTotalText").toggle("fast");
        });
        $("#FreightView").click(function () {
        $("#FreightViewText").toggle("fast");
        });
        </script></div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You forgot to close the `<script>` tag in your insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.innerHTML` doesn't execute script elements. You can use `.html()` in jQuery ...

Or do the sensible thing which is just running that code directly:

```
function pluginOrderTotals(OrderTotals) {
    var orderTotalsHTML = "";
    if (OrderTotals != "") {
        orderTotalsHTML = "<a id='OrderTotals' href=''>Order Totals</a><p id='OrderTotalText'>" + OrderTotals + "</p>";
    }
    document.getElementById("pluginWidgets2Div").innerHTML = orderTotalsHTML;
    $('#OrderTotals').click(function () {
        $('#OrderTotalText').toggle('fast');
    });
}
```

Comment: If you add HTML to the DOM dynamically, will that jQuery execute for the click event?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I don't understand your question, jQuery executing click event has nothing to do with adding html dynamically.

Comment: It may be that adding the .click() after adding the HTML is OK.  If you ran that .click() method in the jQuery .ready() function, it would not work because the target isn't in the DOM.  If you add it to the DOM after you add the HTML you are probably OK.  I tend to us the .on() method so that the events are primed and ready for whenever the HTML is modified.

Comment: @SurrealDreams yes if the jQuery element set is empty, adding events will not do anything and it just fails silently. Here I know the set won't be empty because I just added an element with the id to the dom

Comment: @Esailija That worked. I knew it was something small. I just did the sensible thing ;) like you said. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice unobtrusive way to have this code waiting in the wings so that it will work.  When inserting the HTML, skip the JavaScript - handle it separately.

```
function pluginOrderTotals(OrderTotals) {
    var orderTotalsHTML = "";
    if (OrderTotals != "") {
    orderTotalsHTML = "<a id='OrderTotals' href=''>Order Totals</a><p id='OrderTotalText'>" + OrderTotals + "</p>";
    }
document.getElementById("pluginWidgets2Div").innerHTML = orderTotalsHTML;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pluginWidgets2Div").on("click", "#OrderTotals", function () {
        $("#OrderTotalText").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

The jQuery will apply to the HTML if/when it's inserted, and your HTML doesn't need to have any JavaScript in it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the `<script>` tag:

```
orderTotalsHTML = "<a id='OrderTotals' href='#'>Order Totals</a><p id='OrderTotalText'>" + OrderTotals + "</p><script>$('#OrderTotals').click(function () {  $('#OrderTotalText').toggle('fast');});</script>";
```